# Search Bar Delegate is not called when text is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi in iOS8 as per Apple docs, `UISearchController` override `UISearchDisplayController`. I am trying to do same thing with `UISearchController`, but Delegate method is not getting called.

**I have to call a network request when user input 2 character in search bar.**

My code -

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SearchVC : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>{
UISearchBar* searchBar;
}
@end
```

.m

```
@interface SearchVC () <UISearchResultsUpdating>

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
   [searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
   searchBar.delegate =self;
}


-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
   if ([searchBar.text length] > 2) {
    // Call Network Request
     } 
   else {
    //display result
   }
```

Comment: where u initialize searchbar?

Comment: @AmitShelgaonkar in viewdidload method before delagate check updated quest

Comment: Is your searchBar linked in Interface Builder ?  Where do you add it to the view otherwise ?

Comment: @Justa  same case exists if i linked it with interface builder

Comment: Can you show how and where you init your searchBar and where you add it to the view ?

Comment: @Justa  heh i just draged UISearchBar in .h in storyboard. u need it to see in that way

Comment: @imran it's working when i linked searchbar in IB Try this

Comment: @AmitShelgaonkar i m trying to do when it is linked with IB, but delegate is not getting called